# How to carry out deletions from 2 tables, at the same time in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, transactions, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-delete

Within my `Oracle` database I wish to delete rows from 2 different tables.

The issue is that, if I delete rows from KENNEL first, then the rows I want to delete in DOG table **cannot** be found to delete.

Below are my `SQL statements` to delete from the two tables.

```
DELETE FROM KENNEL WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL;
DELETE FROM DOG WHERE ID IN (SELECT DOG_ID FROM KENNEL WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL);
```

How can I fix this so that the 2 deletes happen at the **same time**, and ensure that rows from both the tables are removed?

Note: I cannot delete from DOG then KENNEL as KENNEL is the child record that must be deleted first.

Comment: You could simply delete first from DOG, then from KENNEL, and handle the exception to rollback both statements if one gives error

Comment: I cannot do so, as there is a constraint between DOG and KENNEL, kennel must be deleted from first as it is a child record

Comment: What kind of constraints have you got on your tables? Please post the code of all involved constraints

Comment: Why can't you just delete from kennel and then delete from dog where the id doesn't exist in the kennel table? That sounds to be the simplest way. That way, if there are still child records left in the kennel table, you won't get an error trying to delete the rows from the dog table. Alternatively, first extract the ids into a collection or global temporary table (GTT), and then use that to base the deletes on.

Comment: @Boneist thanks ill try that, alternatively could I use a join statement to carry out the delete from the 2 schemas?

Comment: Not in Oracle; it's not supported.

Comment: @Boneist ok please detail your answer in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this set of deletes as something like:

```
-- delete rows from child table first
DELETE FROM KENNEL WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL;

-- now delete any parent rows that don't have any child records
DELETE FROM DOG WHERE ID not exists (SELECT DOG_ID FROM KENNEL);
```

Doing it this way means that if not all the country_ids for a given dog_id in the kennel table were null, you wouldn't attempt to delete the parent record - it would error if you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE DOG SET [some non-key field] = 'XXX' WHERE ID IN (SELECT DOG_ID FROM KENNEL WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL);

DELETE FROM KENNEL WHERE COUNTRY_ID IS NULL;

DELETE FROM DOG WHERE [non-key field] = 'XXX';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.